# Import discord.py returns the error " ModuleNotFoundError: aiohttp”

Tags: python, pip, discord.py, python-import

I am working on a project in which you will need to unpack the archive with all the data and everything will work, without installing packages by the user. I came to the creation of a discord bot, but it gives an error, I do not understand what is associated with it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\Project Folder\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import modules.discord
  File "path\Project Folder\modules\discord\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "path\Project Folder\modules\discord\client.py", line 33, in <module>
    import aiohttp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
```

Before that, I downloaded pythonping absolutely as well and there were no errors when importing it.
Downloaded it like this:

```
pip install --target="path\Project Folder\modules" pythonping
pip install --target="path\Project Folder\modules" discord.py
```

The folder where it was downloaded looks like this (initially it was empty):

[image: photo of the directory]

If I change the import of the discord in the same file, and add pythonping, then everything will work without errors.

```
from modules.pythonping import ping
#import modules.discord
import botinfo

print(botinfo.BotTag)
```

At the very end, I manually downloaded the discord archive from [github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) and put it in the modules directory, but since there is no aiohttp, ctrl+click did not redirect to it, after which I already downloaded aiohttp `pip install --target="path\project folder\modules" aiohttp` and ctrl+click began to go to aiohttp, but the error remained (absolutely the same).

Additional information:

```
python --version       Python 3.8.2
pip --version          pip 21.0.1
```

Comment: Does pip list show all the packages?

Comment: @Ceres this? https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/718015270194511903/836869808346890261/unknown.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the python version decided to change from the last to the previous one, which is why discord did not run on the NEW version, because it still took packages not from the project directory, but from the interpreter directory. I switched to an earlier version of python and it worked, then I forcibly downloaded it to the new version and it also worked.

Answer (score -1):

I think running the following command might be a good idea :

```
pip install aiohttp
```